# vectorization : multiply _m256i elements

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I'm looking to multiply all 32 bits integers in a register at once using SIMD instructions, this is what I tried so far :

```
  int32_t a [8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  int32_t b [8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  __m256i tmp1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) a);
  __m256i tmp2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) b);

  __m256 tmp3 = _mm256_mul_epi32(tmp1,tmp2);
```

sadly it doesn't yield correct result, this is basically what I get :
*1, 0, 9, 0, 25, 0, 49, 0*

I haven't found an alternative instruction yet, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply 32 bit integer using `_mm256_mul_epi32`, you will get 64 bit output. `_mm256_mul_epi32` works as follows

```
a[0] * b[0] = tmp3[1:0]    1 * 1 = 1
a[2] * b[2] = tmp3[3:2]    3 * 3 = 9
a[4] * b[4] = tmp3[5:4]    5 * 5 = 25
a[6] * b[6] = tmp3[7:6]    7 * 7 = 49
```

in `tmp3` you have 4 results.

You can try to use `_mm256_mullo_epi32`, this instruction multiplies each element of `a` array by corresponding element of `b` array, but only 32 low bits of 64 bit output are stored as result.

Comment: If this naming seems backwards (i.e. shouldn't the pure 32x32 -> 32-bit multiplication have the simple `mul` name?) then remember that the intrinsics were named for SSE2 `pmuldq` / `pmuludq`, and then years later SSE4.1 `pmulld` gave us `mullo`.  The `__m256i` versions were of course both introduced at the same time, with AVX2.

Comment: This is documented in the intrinsics guide: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&ig_expand=5055,4913&text=_mm256_mul - note how `_mm256_mul_epi32` writes 4 64-bit destination elements, not 8x 32-bit elements.